# Unable to add another time zone in clock

Tags: time, clock, date

I am unable to add another time zone in the clock.
Currently i am in India and also want to add Sydney in the clock but when i try to add locations from the Choose locations tab, it doesn't show/recognize the city i enter.
It comes up with a red circle (like Do Not Disturb icon in office communicator)
I tried to report a bug but it shows package clock doesn't exist.